# Metric perturbation calculations in xAct

Tags: xact

Any hints to calculating the following two-point function, which is not time-ordered, in xAct?

$$
    \begin{equation}
    <h_{\mu\nu}(x) h_{\alpha\beta}(y)>
    \end{equation}
$$

```
<< xAct`xPert` 
DefManifold[M4, 4, {a, b, c, d, e, f, g, h, i, j, k, l}] DefMetric[-1, metric[-i, -j], CD, SymbolOfCovD -> {"|","\ [Del]"},PrintAs -> "g"] 
DefMetricPerturbation[metric, metpert, [Epsilon]]; 
PrintAs[metpert] ^= "h"; 
ExpandPerturbation@Perturbation[metric[-i, -j], 1]
```

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: << xAct`xPert`
       
    DefManifold[M4, 4, {a, b, c, d, e, f, g, h, i, j, k, l}]
    DefMetric[-1, metric[-i, -j], CD, SymbolOfCovD -> {"|","\                        
    [Del]"},PrintAs -> "g"]
    DefMetricPerturbation[metric, metpert, \[Epsilon]];
    PrintAs[metpert] ^= "h";
    ExpandPerturbation@Perturbation[metric[-i, -j], 1]

Comment: this is what I have done so far, generating the first order metric perturbation only. Any suggestions how to go from here? @CATrevillian

Comment: NovoGrav, can you, please, update your question with this information? It is better to do that, as it can get lost or overlooked in the comments. Thanks!

Comment: the code is added in the main question. thanks. @CATrevillian